# How to ignore JSON processing for a request in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a request handler for which I would like to skip json processing and retrieve the request body as a string. Eg -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/webhook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void webHook(@RequestBody String body) {

}
```

However, the above method definition doesnt work as Spring forcibly tries to parse the posted string as json and thus throws an exception.

How do i tell spring to skip json processing for this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this it'll work.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/webhook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void webHook(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String body = IOUtils.toString( request.getInputStream());
    // do stuff
}
```

Not using `@RequestBody` is key here. When spring sees `@RequestBody` it tries to map the entire body as object.